# Why does the command ps not display the entire list of processes?

Tags: grep, process, ps

If the command `ps awx | grep -v grep` is run the following output is produced. The list below is the last 20 lines of the complete output.

```
 4247 pts/1    Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash
 4442 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/u17:1]
 4661 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/u17:3]
 4731 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/u17:5]
 4734 ?        S      0:00 pickup -l -t fifo -u
 4847 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/u17:7]
 4850 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u16:3]
 4878 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u16:0]
 5201 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/u17:8]
 5353 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:1]
 5354 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/7:2]
 5355 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u16:2]
 5361 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/4:0]
 5362 tty1     Ss     0:00 -bash
 5396 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/6:0]
 5418 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:0]
 5420 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/2:2]
 5431 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/7:0]
 5562 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/4:2]
 5620 tty1     R+     0:00 ps awx
```

If a subsequent command `ps awx | grep grep` is run the following output is generated.

```
5646 tty1     S+     0:00 grep --color=auto grep
```

Additionally if the following command `ps awx | grep agetty` is run, the following output is displayed.

```
5669 tty1     S+     0:00 grep --color=auto agetty
```

Why does the command `ps awx` not display the process identification numbers 5646 and 5669? In fact there are no other processes listed after 5620.

Comment: Show the complete list of `ps awx`. From the initial looks `5646` is not even there in your given information

Comment: @Inian OP already mentioned `5646` showed up in subsequent command, so it's a new process and couldn't have been in the original (or complete list) of `ps awx` in the first place

Comment: @Motivated Let me make sure before I write an answer: are you asking why there is no 5647, 5648, 5649...and so on ? Is that correct ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - That is correct. I also updated the preceding command in the question.

Comment: @Motivated  So I've posted an answer, and I think it's fairly solid, though let me know if anything is unclear there or something needs to be added. And hope it clarifies a thing or two.

Comment: It would be useful & valuable understand the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the command ps awx not display the process identification numbers 5646 and 5669?

Because you only started `5646` as part of the command `ps awx | grep grep`, and `5669` as part of the `ps awx | grep agetty` command. They were started after that initial listing, so weren't visible in it. Both ran until they had processed the input from the `ps` process in that particular pipeline, so they wouldn't be visible in any later listings either.

Similarly, if you run `ps` repeatedly, you'll see the process id change: every time you run the command, a new process is started.

---

More specifically, the second process in question was this:

```
5669 tty1     S+     0:00 grep --color=auto agetty
```

This is `grep`, which has been given the arguments `--color=auto` and `agetty`. This matches the `grep` command in `ps awx | grep agetty`, the `--color=auto` flag probably comes from some alias. It's not an `agetty` process. One of those would probably have `agetty` or `/sbin/agetty` as the first part of the command line, as in this example from a Debian system:

```
1269 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty3 linux
```

Comment: I would have thought that `agetty` would have existed prior to the command `ps awx | grep agetty` being executed. This is because it launched the shell and other services once the user logged in. Do you mean to say that `agetty` is terminated once logged in. The feedback regarding `ps awx | grep grep ` makes sense.

Comment: @Motivated, no, that's not `agetty`, that's `grep`.  Edited.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean to say the output `5669 tty1     S+     0:00 grep --color=auto agetty` is not a representation of `agetty` and that it`s `grep`? If yes, is 5669 indicating a grep process? If so, is `agetty` at the end noting that its the output of the command `5669 tty1     S+     0:00 grep --color=auto agetty`? If that's the case, i wasn't aware of that. My impression had been that `agetty` was the process associated with the process identification number 5669.

Comment: @Motivated, I'm not sure how to clarify that without repeating myself. In the listings in your question, it should be clear that `5620` is `ps` with the argument `awx`. Similarly, `5646` is `grep` with the arguments `--color=auto grep`, and `5669` is `grep` with the arguments `--color=auto agetty`. In all cases, the arguments given to the commands show in last columns. There's no reason for an `agetty` process to have a name of `grep`, but if you're grepping for `agetty`, there's very much a reason for `grep` to have an argument of `agetty`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that since i was operating under the assumption that the output was an indication of the process for which grep was used for e.g. agetty.

Answer (score 2):

Processes can come and go within microseconds via `fork()`, both inside kernel and outside. In fact, to quote [Michael Foukarakis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446727/how-does-linux-determine-the-next-pid/3457108#3457108):

> The reason for PIDs not appearing sequential in user space is because kernel scheduling might fork a process in between your process' fork() calls. It's very common, in fact.

So between `ps awx | grep -v grep` and `ps awx | grep grep` a lot of things happened. There were new processes and threads - they just exited before `ps` could capture them. The same logic occurs in your `ps awx | grep grep` and last example. But also note that `grep` PID may not in fact be newest, because as  [Gilles in related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37597/85039) points out:

> [p]iped commands run concurrently. When you run ps | grep …, it's the luck of the draw (or a matter of details of the workings of the shell combined with scheduler fine-tuning deep in the bowels of the kernel) as to whether ps or grep starts first, and in any case they continue to execute concurrently.

Note also that `grep -v grep` is intended to remove itself from `ps` output (and generally it is actually recommended to use `| grep -v [g]rep` in such case, see [related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74186/85039) ).

Comment: Do you mean to say that each time i run `ps awx` for example, the output could differ? Additionally, what do you mean by 'inside the kernel and outside`?

Comment: @Motivated   Yes,  each time you run `ps awx` the difference in time between when you run the commands can be seconds (depending on how fast you type). But processes come and co within microseconds or nanoseconds.   As for the other question, there's two notions: userspace and kernel space. Userspace is where user stuff runs - like commands, services, terminal, root services. Kernel processes come from kernel. `[kworker]` is an example. Those processes manage low level stuff - memory,   hardware, disks and filesystems.

Comment: If the command `ps awx` results in differing output each time, how does one monitor the behavior of a particular process? As for the differences in userspace and the kernel, do you mean to say that there are 2 sets of processes being produced? Are the independent of one another? I would imagine that processes in the userspace are dependent on the processes that the kernel is running?

Comment: I can't say if userspace processes depend on kernel processes. Some might, in order to query information only kernel can provide. By the way, [Are threads implemented as processes on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364663/85039) might be interesting as well.  As for monitoring specific process, well, it depends: you can either start a process, record its PID, and keep watching until that PID is on the list of processes, or have to brute force - run `ps` or `pgrep` frequently, which traverses all `/proc` directory till it finds matching process

Comment: @Motivated Difference between userspace and kernelspace: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87625/85039

Comment: According to `man grep` `-v` is  or `--invert match` is      `Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.`. That suggests that it lists all other findings other than `grep` in this instance.

Comment: @Motivated Yes, correct. `grep -v 'pattern'` will not show `pattern` - it will be filtered out. But remember that even though `grep` will  filter itself out from output of `ps` it still exists as process. In other words, just because you don't see its PID it doesn't mean it doesn't exist

Comment: `| grep [g]rep` doesn't make much sense, the pattern `[g]rep` would still match the process name `grep` on the same command.